# Best Possible Way to retrieve image from database in javascript or jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

Want to know what could be the best possible way to retrieve the images stored from database in javascript or jquery.

Currently i am retrieving the image from database and storing into one temp folder into server side and in the javascript with the help of  i am retrieving that particular image.

But i am looking for some other way to retrieving the image directly from db without storing into temp folder.

Tried my best to brief the problem.If unable to get Let me know i will try in some other way.

Comment: how is the image stored in the database? a path, a url, base64 string?

your question is super vague.some example code and more information would help

Comment: You want to save the whole image in database itself ? Bad idea dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach would be saving the image path in the database and storing the image in a generic location. You can either save path and the name of the image in two columns in the database or concatenate and save in one column.

However the image should be saved under a generic location or in rare cases in specific location.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid storing files themselves in the database, thats a very heavy way of doing it.  Store the file location instead, with the images in a folder on the server.

If you then want to retrieve the locations and you want to stick to client side for non-refresh purposes, you could use ajax to query the server then return the file location.

Answer (score 0):

Well answering the actual question asked rather than providing alternatives: you use a servlet to stream the image data to the client and then you reference the servlet in your img tag. For example, use BalusC's ImageServlet so you don't have to re-invent the wheel:

http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2007/04/imageservlet.html

Comment: And a side note: I am not qualified to judge what the BEST POSSIBLE WAY is, this is just a way that works. I hope it is good enough.